Node.js Express allowing importing JS modules from local directory outside the app
I would like to share JS code (utilities.js) between web projects on the same server for use between client-side Node.js Express scripts. I'm trying to utilize ES6 module imports for this purpose.
The problem is: it has become apparent that my Express set-up doesn't permit imports from outside the working express.static directory (i.e. /public, "client-side").
I can achieve module import through various approaches, but as soon as I put utilities.js above public an import call from within script.js cannot access it.
-app.js
-project
-project
-project
--index.js
--public
---script.js
-utilities
--utilities.js
in app.js:
express.static(`./project/public`)(req, res, next);
app.use(`/project`, `./project/index.js`);

in html:
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "u": "./../../utilities/utilities.js"
    }
  }
</script>

in script.js:
import wow from 'u';
alert(wow.woo());

in utilities.js:
function woo() {
    return "woo";
}
export default { woo };

Question: How can I import (i.e. share) utilities.js between projects?
Ideas: Do I need to add more static routes? Is this a node or express config issue? Is CORS the problem here? Is server -> client browser import just not intended? Should I instead approach like req to index.js -> readFile('/path/utilities.js)' -> dynamic import? Is app.use(express.static('utilities')) a better approach?

Ended up using res.sendFile() to serve the js file and module language to import it into my client-side script. Did not see this particular solution anywhere, but works like a charm. Note if you're coming at this from scratch, the other adjustment was to add "type": "module" to package.json to get ES6 modules working.
in app.js:
express.static(`./project/public`)(req, res, next);
app.use(`/project`, `./project/index.js`);    
app.get('/utilities.js', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(`${path.resolve('./','utilities')}/utilities.js`);
});

in html:
<script type="importmap">
    {
       "imports": {
       "u": "/utilities.js"
    }
}
</script>
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>

in script.js:
import * as u from 'u';
alert(u.woo())

in utilities.js:
export function woo() {
  return "woo";
}

Loading the page alerts "woo". Looking forward to building a portable single server-side file of client-side js functions.
